# Is 'Significance test for Lasso' justified?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, lasso

[Lockhart *et al*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7161) described a "Significance test for the lasso", the motivating example for which is forward variable selection in a linear regression. In their Figures 1 and 2 they show Q-Q plots of a naive chi-square test on the selected variable and using their new $T$ statistic, which takes an exponential distribution. My question: is the naive chi-square test a strawman test? Wouldn't one, instead, apply the most basic correction for multiple hypothesis testing here?

In the figure below I replicate Figure 2 (a) from the paper, getting an essentially normal test statistic, zero mean under the null, grabbing the maximal chi-square, and Q-Q plotting against a chi-square with 1 degree of freedom. On the right I correct for taking the maximum of $p=10$ chi-squares using the beta distribution.

*Why is the naive chi-square test the benchmark against which to evaluate this new $T$ statistic, instead of a basic corrected test*?

[image: QQ plots against naive chi-square, and corrected]

Code to make these plots:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(mvtnorm)

n <- 100
p <- 10

set.seed(12345)  # mental note: change your password
twoa <- replicate(1000,{
          X <- rmvnorm(n=n,sigma=diag(p))
          muhat <- colMeans(X)
          # Sghat <- cov(X)
          # the F statistic uses Sghat, but
          # we assume orthogonality, so just do the chi-squares?
          # not sure why n is relevant, actually
          chisqs <- n * muhat^2
          max(chisqs)
         })

ph1 <- data_frame(sample=twoa) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample=sample)) +
  stat_qq(distribution=qchisq,dparams=list(df=1)) +
  geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0) +
  labs(y='Test statistic',x='Chi-squared on 1 df',
       title='Forward stepwise (Fig 2 (a))')

# but better to compare against max of chi squares
qmaxchisq <- function(p,df,nover) { qchisq(p=qbeta(p,shape1=nover,shape2=1),df=df) }

ph2 <- data_frame(sample=twoa) %>%
  ggplot(aes(sample=sample)) +
  stat_qq(distribution=qmaxchisq,dparams=list(df=1,nover=p)) +
  geom_abline(slope=1,intercept=0) +
  labs(y='Test statistic',x='max of 10 Chi-squared on 1 df',
       title='Forward stepwise, corrected for multiple hypothesis testing')

require(cowplot)
plot_grid(ph1,ph2,labels='AUTO')
```

Comment: are they looking at parameter-wise error rates (rather than model-wise error rates)?